# Assembly on the LC3 and a weird JSR command

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm trying to decipher some basic LC3 code and I'm thrown off by a specific line ..

**Address**

```
x3122 : 0100 01010 0110 0110
```

Now I understand that this is a JSRR opcode, but I'm thrown off by what comes after the opcode, specifically bits 10 and 9. Aren't those bits supposed to be 0?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm the binary you gave is 17 bits is that a mistake?

I will assume you meant

0100010100110011

It is indeed a JSRR since the opcode is 0100 and bit 11 is 0

following that is 2 unused bits, 3 bits for base register, followed by another 6 unused bits. Both of these unused sections should be all zeroes.

0100 0 10 100 110011

If I were to disassemble this instruction back to assembly langauge this would be `JSRR R4`

However some lc-3 simulators may treat instructions whose unused bits don't conform to the ISA (such as the one you posted) as an error, since the assembler will simply fill unused bits as 0 (and in the case of the NOT instruction those unused bits are 1's).

Comment: aha , I see. I guess i was confused about those unused bits,  I was unsure if they had any purpose.

Comment: its 0100 0101 0110 0110

Comment: so is that JSRR R5?

Comment: Im confused as to what that line does on this example ... Because I dont understand where the R5 is coming from ...

Comment: R5  comes from the bits in the instruction bits [6:8] since its 101 we want R5.

JSRR does the following
R7 <- PC
PC = BaseR

So stick R5's value into the PC.